# Return a view from Post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this post method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Invitations(SuperInvitationsEditModel model)
    {
        ...

        var newmodel = new SuperInvitationsEditModel();

        if (hasErrors)
        {
            SuperInvitationsErrorModel newErrorModel = new SuperInvitationsErrorModel();
            newErrorModel.Errors = model.Errors;
            return View(newErrorModel);
        }

        return View(newmodel);
        }
```

When this code in the if(hasErrors) executes I get this error.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.Models.SuperInvitationsErrorModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models.SuperInvitationsEditModel'.
```

I thought I can do this since the return value of the method is a generic ActionResult. Can anyone tell me why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because your current view is strongly typed. change the code as

```
 return View("yourviewname",newErrorModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with casting *ViewResult* to *ActionResult*. The problem is, that you have strongly typed view that expects the model of type `SuperInvitationsEditModel` (see `@model` on the top of *Invitations.cshtml*), but you are passing the model of type `SuperInvitationsErrorModel` to it.

You should merge the two view model classes (*SuperInvitationsEditModel* and *SuperInvitationsErrorModel*) into one, or create a standalone view for each of them.